# obtener ip/hostname kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ip

intento obtener ip y hostname de los distintos dispositivos de mi red desde kotlin y llenar con esos datos un recyclerview con un for, pero no logro hacerlo andar.

Busco determinado hostname para que me devuelva el ip de esta manera:

```
 val addr = InetAddress.getByName("K50").hostAddress
 //val host = addr.hostName
 Log.d("console", addr.toString()) 
 //Log.d("console", host.toString())
```

Sin exito tampoco entiendo como pasar el bytearray para InetAddress.getByAddress(), para asi poder buscar el dispositivo y su hostname con el ip. Desde ya muchas gracias, su ayuda seria invaluable para mi, dado que soy novato.

Answer (score 0):

**Como obtener IP en Kotlin**

Para obtener la IP del dispositivo lo ideal es usar la clase [**NetworkInterface**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface), esta es una funciòn que podrìas utilizar, incluso puedes obtener IPs v4.

```
fun getIPHostAddress(): String {
    NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()?.toList()?.map { networkInterface ->
        networkInterface.inetAddresses?.toList()?.find {
            !it.isLoopbackAddress && it is Inet4Address
        }?.let { return it.hostAddress }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Buinisimo!! sos un crack jorge te la sabes todas. Si bien no sabia como ver la ip del celular, yo lo que quiero es descubrir otros dispositivos!, su ip y hostname, y no se como pasarle un parametro de ip o hostname a esa funcion, espero haberme explicado, perdon por ser tan novicio jaja